# Custom properties field for message in vsto Outlook item disappears after reaching recipient

Tags: outlook

We developed a plug-in in Outlook, we need to set the custom properties of the program for an email, and we hope that the properties will not be lost when the email is sent to other recipients. How to deal with this requirement?

I've tried UserProperties in Mailitem as well as PropertyAccessor objects to set custom properties, but neither have good results.

Comment: How's everything going now?

Answer (score 0):

This?
Outlook-Add-in-Store-Custom-Properties-On-Exchange-Server
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/outlook-add-in-store-custom-properties-on-exchange-server/outlook-add-in-store-custom-properties-on-exchange-server/

Comment: Any update about this issue? Please do not forget to mark the helpful reply as the answer. Thanks! : )